# Alterar o texto do Botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gostaria de alterar o texto do botão após a confirmação leitura,contudo como tenho varios elementos iguais no DOM,com faço alterar apenas o texto do botão em questão.

```
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="DEI-DAF020.001.000 - DEI - TI SUPORTE.pdf" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="teste1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Segue um exemplo!

Após capturar o elemento clicado pela class, basta você usar this, para indicar que deseja mudar o elemento clicado!

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e){
  $(this).text("mudei");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="DEI-DAF020.001.000 - DEI - TI SUPORTE.pdf" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="teste1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
```

Comment: Pensei nessa forma de implementação,contudo estou desenvolvendo para no ERP Fluig da Totvs ,que suas especificação.Sem falar que evento click iria capturar o click do btn do modal,pois tem btn que abre modal que outro btn confirmação.No caso queria alterar texto do 1º botão.

Comment: é só um exemplo, você pode adicionar uma class especifica para os btns do modal, assim o click ira funcionar sem problema!

Answer (score 1):

E se fosse feito desta maneira? Você só colocaria o evento de onClick no próprio botão que você quer ter essa confirmação. E até poderia passar alguma outra informação para fazer um if, caso fosse necessário.

```js
confirmaLeitura = (elemento)=>{
  elemento.textContent = "Leitura Confirmada";
}
```

```html
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="DEI-DAF020.001.000 - DEI - TI SUPORTE.pdf" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738" onClick="confirmaLeitura(this)">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Este botão não terá confirmação</button></td>
<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="teste1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738" onClick="confirmaLeitura(this)">Confirma Leitura</button></td>
```

Comment: Tentar ser mais claro,ambas sugestão de implementação não me atende,pois o fluxo e o seguinte;tenho um botão aonde abre o um modal com um termo,quando usuário clicar no botão de confirmação do modal,ai sim alterar o texto do botão que exibe o modal.

Answer (score 1):

Eu prefiro essa abordagem! Qualquer dúvida grita ai. Fica com Deus!

```js
        const btn = document.querySelectorAll('#dados')

        btn.forEach(x => {
            x.addEventListener('click', () => x.innerHTML = "Leitura Confirmada")
        })
```

```html
        <td class="btnDoc">
            <button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="DEI-DAF020.001.000 - DEI - TI SUPORTE.pdf" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button>
        </td>
        <td class="btnDoc">
            <button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button>
        </td>
        <td class="btnDoc">
            <button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="teste1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Confirma Leitura</button>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br">
<html></br><center> 
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="btnDoc"><button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="teste1" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Mudar de nome</button></td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn").click(function copiar(){
  $(this).text("Nome mudado");
});
    </script></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).